# C++ Get name of a template function argument

Tags: c++, templates

I want to replace all `glXXXX` calls to `GL_CALL(N, ...)` so that I can print function and arguments to trace the calls.

For example, replace `glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)` to `GL_CALL(ClearColor, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)` and in console I get `[GL_CALL] glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1)`

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
void GL_TRACE_PRINT(T const &t) {
  std::cout << t << ",";
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void GL_TRACE_PRINT(T n, Args ... args) {
  GL_TRACE_PRINT(n);
  GL_TRACE_PRINT(args...);
}

#define GL_STR(s) #s

template <class F, typename ...Args>
auto GL_INVOKE(F f, Args && ...args) {
  std::cout << "[GL_CALL] " << GL_STR(f) << '(';
  GL_TRACE_PRINT(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  std::cout << ")\n";
  return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

#define GL_CALL(N, ...)                                       \
  GL_INVOKE(gl##N, __VA_ARGS__);
```

But how to print the function name in `GL_INVOKE`? Thanks.
Or is there better way to do so?

Currently the output is, the `glXXX` function names are all `f`.

```
[GL_CALL] f(0,0,0,1,)
[GL_CALL] f(0,0,0,1,)
```

Comment: `__function__` macro?

Comment: If you want to trace the call, I suggest you using some macro, such as `__line__`, `__function` etc. Or, you can use `boost.stacktrace`. Or you can use things in `<stacktrace>` if you work with C++23.

Comment: `__FUNCTION__` macro outputs "[GL_CALL] GL_INVOKE(0,0,0,1,)" @JohnFilleau

Comment: add a two params GL_TRACE_PRINT will help remove the last "," :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the string name of the function into `GL_INVOKE`, something like this:

```
template <class F, typename ...Args>
auto GL_INVOKE(const char* fname, F f, Args && ...args) {
  std::cout << "[GL_CALL] " << fname << '(';
  GL_TRACE_PRINT(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  std::cout << ")\n";
  return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

#define GL_INVOKE_F(N, ...) \
  GL_INVOKE(#N, N, ## __VA_ARGS__) 

#define GL_CALL(N, ...)  \
  GL_INVOKE_F(gl##N , ## __VA_ARGS__)
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/13oeEbzYz)

In addition, your `GL_TRACE_PRINT` can be implemented using C++17 fold expression, which will be much more concise.

```
template <class... Args>
void GL_TRACE_PRINT(Args const&... args) {
  ((std::cout << args << ","), ...);
}
```

Comment: Haha, thanks. That's smart.

Comment: By the way. For glCreateProgram without any argument. GL_CALL fail to compile.error: expected expression
    GLuint program = GL_CALL(CreateProgram);note: expanded from macro 'GL_CALL'
  GL_INVOKE(GL_STR(gl##N), gl##N, __VA_ARGS__)

Comment: How can I fix the template so that it can accept glFunction without any arugments? Thanks.

Comment: @wqyfavor. You can use `##` to remove the comma, see updated.

Comment: @wqyfavor If you use your template for all of your funcitons, in the worst case, the size of your bin file would explode.